# Emberjs model find method not populating the template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have my routes set up as

```
# ROUTER MAPPING
App.Router.map( ->
  this.resource("alertInstances", 
    path:"/"
  )

  this.resource("alertInstance", 
    path:"/:alertInstance_id"
  )
)

# ALERT INSTANCES ROUTE
App.AlertInstancesRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    App.AlertInstance.all()

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set("content", model)
)

# ALERT INSTANCE ROUTE
App.AlertInstanceRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: (params) ->
    App.AlertInstance.find(params.alertInstance_id)

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set("content", model)
)
```

When I go to the route "/" I get a list of all "alert instances" and I click one and it shows the details of a single "alert instance".

My model object is set up as below.

```
# ALERT INSTANCE MODEL
App.AlertInstance = Ember.Object.extend()
App.AlertInstance.reopenClass(
  allAlertInstances: []
  currAlertInstance:null
  all: ->
    @allAlertInstances = []
    $.ajax
      url:base + "api/alert_instances"
      dataType: "JSON"
      context:this 
      success: (response) ->
    for i in response
      i.clinical = if i.alert_type is "clinical" then true else false
      @allAlertInstances.addObject App.AlertInstance.create(i)
    @allAlertInstances
)
```

This all works very well. But when the user goes directly to "/10" (by specifying the alert instance ID), since no data has been retrieved from the server, there is nothing to display.

So I added the following "find" method

```
find: (id) ->
  @currAlertInstance = null
  $.ajax 
    url:base + "api/alert_instance"
    dataType:"JSON"
    context:this
    data:
      id:id
      success: (response) ->
        @currAlertInstance = App.AlertInstance.create(response)
        @currAlertInstance
  @currAlertInstance
```

But the view is empty and nothing is displayed.

I can see in my Chrome console network that a single alert instance JSON object has been indeed returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use render in Route to render a template.

```
App.AlertInstancesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.render([<handlebar_name>], {
       [outlet: <outlet_name>],
       [into: <template_name_to_render_to>]
    });
  },

  model: function(params) {
    App.AlertInstance.all();
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set("content", model);
  }
})
```

For more information please follow [this link](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L400)